# get all Navigator Object and save to file with Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have problem converting a multidimensional object into an array and save it in local file file.json

my problem is with JSON.stringify(myobj); it doesn't convert all the multidimensional object.
the below code get all the navigator properties in Object but when I convert it to an array or trying JSON.stringify I lost a lot of values like "plugin" it turned to an empty array .

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


    var myobj = {};
    var str;
    for(var property in navigator){ 
        var str = navigator[property]
        document.write(property+ "&nbsp;&nbsp;<em>"+str+"</em><br />");

    myobj[property] = str;

    } 
    var params = JSON.stringify(myobj);
        console.log(myobj);
        console.log(params); // Some array values is missing like plugins !


         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: params,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'json.php',
            success: function(data){
                alert('DONE');
            },
            error: function(){
               alert('Error');
            }
    }); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLMRF.png)